# How to check if a row of the first column is similar to the second?

Tags: php, mysql

I use the query

```
Select t1.name as first, t2.name as second From products t1, products t2
```

that creates two columns like below. (A,B are for explaining purposes)

Before the query

```
-name-
A
B
C
D
E
```

After the query

```
-first- -second-
A        A
B        A
C        A
D        A
E        A
A        B
B        B
C        B
D        B
E        B
```

How to check if a row of the first column is similar to the second ?

**UPDATE**

I run mySQL

With similar, I mean like to find their similarity percentage are more of a specified value. Like if the first contains `this is a string` and second `i wear a string` there is a percentage of similarity. If this % is more than 70 then they are similar.

Comment: What do you mean by similar? Identical?

Comment: I mean like to find their similarity percentage are more of a specified value. Like if the first contains `this is a string` and second `i wear a string` there is a percentage of similarity. If this % is more than 70 then they are similar.

Comment: what db are you running?

Comment: Are you ok with running a script on your db first to generate the values? or does it need to be more dynamic than that?

Comment: @Juventus18 Yes, I am ok with that. I am running mySQL

Comment: @JPampos: Would a word per word comparison suffice? For that I'd say PHP would provide the better solution. What I'd do is load words in an array and then compare the elements between them.

Comment: @James Poulson - Yes a word per word would be great. Also an array of common words to ignore?

Comment: To filter words in PHP you can do something like this:

`function filter_words( $words )
{
    $filters = array('the', 'and');

    foreach( $filters as $filter ) {
        return strpos($words, $filter) === false;
    }
    
    return true;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways, here is one that will give you all the products that match your criteria (first = second)

```
SELECT
  t1.name AS first, t2.name AS second 
FROM
  products t1, products t2
WHERE
  t1.name = t2.name
```

or, if you need all the values

```
Select
  t1.name as first t2.name as second, (if t1.name = t2.name THEN 1 ELSE 0) as match
From 
  products t1, products t2
```

Comment: Please see my updated question where I explain what I mean with similar.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what to do.

1. run the select script like you do to get all possible
   combinations you want to calculate.
2. make a php script that loops
   through each of these and calculates the percentage of similarity by
   using similar_text function in php
   (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)
3. write all three values to a new table
4. now just query the new table
   getting all rows where the percent is greater than 70.